# Scala's apply method

Tags: scala

I am constructing a List in Scala as below:

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3) //This is otherwise: List.apply(1,2,3) ---> A
```

Now I have the below line.

```
list1(1) //which is otherwise list1.apply(1)  ---> B
```

Above line returns 2 which is of type Int.

Line A and B are calls to apply method in the List class. Method overloading  certainly can not be present in List class. Then based on what the compiler treats A and B differently ?

Can anyone please help me to understand this.
Thanks!

Comment: Lines A and B are _not_ calls to the apply method in the List class. Line B is, but Line A is a call to the apply method on the List _companion object_, hence the different behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different types at play here.  In your second example, you are calling the `apply` instance method on your instance of the List class.  In your first example, you aren't calling anything on the List class at all, you are calling the apply method on the List companion object.

in the line

```
 val list1 = List(1,2,3)
```

You can tell that in this context you are calling a method on the companion object because you don't have an instance of List and are seemingly calling apply on the class itself.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand the concept!

Answer (score 1):

There are two apply methods here: the `List.apply` and `LinearSeqOptimized.apply`. The main difference is, when you call `List(1, 2, 3)` you're using List companion object apply method and, when you call `list1(1)` you're using the apply's method inherited from `LinearSeqOptimized` trait (which `List` class inherits from).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Above answers explains the reasons well. Let me explain it in more details.

When you invoke `val list1 = List(1,2,3)`, you are invoking a object `List` which is a companion object of class `List` and which in turns invoke `.apply()` method and return instance of class `List`.

```
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList //return instance of class List.
```

Now, if you look into class `List`:

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with LinearSeq[A] with Product with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, List]  with LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]] {...}
```

You can see that it inherit trait `LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]]`. And if you look into this trait you can see an `apply()` method as

```
  /** Selects an element by its index in the $coll.
   *  Note: the execution of `apply` may take time proportional to the index value.
   *  @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if `idx` does not satisfy `0 <= idx < length`.
   */
  def apply(n: Int): A = {
    val rest = drop(n)
    if (n < 0 || rest.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("" + n)
    rest.head
  }
```

That means, class `List` will also inherit this `.apply` method. Therefore, when you invoke `list1(1)`, you are actually invoking this apply method, which return particular index value of the list.

To conclude, in first code, you are invoking `.apply` method of companion object `List` which create list and return instance of class `List` and in second case, you are invoking `.apply` method of class `List` which return particular value of that list.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!